# Common Expression for Coming Together

Tags: idioms, expressions

Is there a common expression to describe a situation where everything comes together perfectly?

UPDATE: The phrase that kept going through my head was "perfect storm," but that holds more of a negative connotation.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of "coming together" you're referring to? There are a number of good words and idioms that might fit, I think, but they refer to different types of situations.

Comment: _It all clicked into place._

Comment: Or "it all fell into place". Or "everything came up (smelling like) roses".

Comment: @JohnLawler That's the one I was going to recommend, I'd add it as an upvotable answer if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider **[when the stars are in alignment](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=when%20the%20stars%20align)** (or *when the stars align*)

> When an unexpected and nearly impossible event takes place. Usually due to pure luck or the divine intervention of God.

Or if you want to wax more lyrical

> *When the moon is in the Seventh House*
>
> *And Jupiter aligns with Mars*
>
> *Then peace will guide the planets*
>
> *And love will steer the stars*

That will be the dawning of the [Age of Aquarius](http://www.metrolyrics.com/aquarius-lyrics-hair.html)